# How to convert benzene to 2-nitrostyrene as the major product?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, nitro-compounds

How to convert benzene to 2-nitrostyrene as the major product?

[image]

I actually came up with a conversion but I don't know if it's correct or not:

[image]

Comment: Since nitro is a ring deactivator, I think we can use $\ce{CH2=CH-Cl + AlCl3}$ to create a polymer. I am not sure though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Brominate to form bromobenzene
2. Nitrate and separate by column chromatography to isolate *o*-nitrobromobenzene ([read](http://juliethahn.com/JMHVersion-Nitration%20of%20bromobenzene.pdf))
3. Vinylate with vinylboroxane/Pd(PPh3)4/K2CO3/DME
   Reference: J.Org. Chem. **67** (2002) 4968, Review JCS Chem. Comm. **2009** 20-33

Comment: Well thanks for the answer...i have never heard of the reaction in the third step....but still...thank you!!

Comment: The exact transformation is described in the JoC reference if you can get to it. It appears in a table in the review article with 74% yield.

Comment: Okay... I'll see if i can get to it somehow! Ty!